# Asynchronous event execution using websockets

Tags: c#

I have windows application that communicates to server via websockets, I use meteor server as server
and websockets4net for communication in client. when send some messages to server(json format).
server will respond to websocket in different order. I can keep track of messages sent to server.
In c# can we have produce consumer pattern, where I can store messageid and callback in dictionary
and execute callback when response recieved.

```
//<int, Action>(<messageid,Callback delegate>)
ConcurrentDictionary<int, Action> serverResponseCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Action>();

public send(JObject message,Action Callback)
{
      socket.Send(message);
      serverResponseCollection.Add(message.id,Callback);
}

void socket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //server response contains message id
    //get callback function and execute
    var callbackObj = serverResponseCollection[e.id];
    Callback();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to associate different callback to every request you send to server?

Comment: yes, I call different server methods, may return different response, can be handled independently.

Comment: can you show me what you doing in client.Execute("ConfirmOrder",callback) ?

Comment: I have edited question, we are executing delegate when server response received. Is there any alternatives when we work with webscokets in this kind of scenarios

Comment: and you mean you can have various callbacks depending on the server method you have called? I mean if you call, let say, GetUser on the server then you will call ProcessUser() on client or if you call GetAllUsers on server then you call ProcessAllUsers on client?

Comment: yes exactly this is the case

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field called "Method" to the json object and set its value to the name of operation you are performing while creating a request message.

```
message.Add("Method", "GetUser");
```

The serve will also add "Method" field in the response with the same value the client has sent in the request.

And then in your response handler you can parse the value of Method field to know which operation you need to perform. And you will also get rid from mapping the message ids with callbacks.

Comment: You are correct,but  my application is multi threaded, many threads may call same server methods and response will be different, we cant handle response in this scenario.

Comment: Then your question is incomplete. You should modify it first.